# Pass environment variable to sudo

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, sudo

I must pass an environment variable to `sudo`, but I am not successful and cannot understand how to get it working:

```
$sudo TEST=MY_TEST --user=myuser --login echo "$TEST"
$
```

The output is empty, but `export` shows me the following:

```
$sudo TEST=MY_TEST --user=myuser --login export
...
declare -x TEST="MY_TEST"
...
```

The environment variable should not be declared in the calling shell. It should be declared locally and directly passed to the `sudo` command.
Can someone help me to pass an environment variable to `sudo` without using `export` in the calling shell.

Answer (score 7):

As you have used double quotes the variable expansion, `"$TEST"`, the expansion is happening before the `sudo` command runs, so the `echo` is seeing the argument as empty as the variable expansion already resulted in null string.

You can leverage a shell here:

```
% sudo TEST=MY_TEST sh -c 'echo "$TEST"'              
MY_TEST
```

Comment: The command is dynamically created in a larger context and one benefit of `sudo` is that the actual command to run can directly appended without the need for quoting. The problem with the `-c` option is that the command must be quoted. Do you know a solution without the need for quoting?

Comment: what if I need to pass two variables?